# Why is my `configureCell:` method called every time I change the value of the object the cell corresponds to? (But I DON'T save it.)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm making an app where when you select a cell, you're segued to a new view for reading. The cell you tapped on corresponds to an object in the Core Data store (through `NSFetchedResultsController`) and that object is set as the value for the `article` property of the view that is being segued to.

Once there, I move the position of the user in the article as they read it. (So I alter the `position` attribute of `article` via `article.position = ...`)

However, this occurs very frequently as they read, often hundreds of times, and each time `NSFetchedResultsController` is detecting the change as an update, then calling `configureCell:`, which then runs through a bunch of configuration for that cell. As this `configureCell:` method is called so often (and I only want it to be called when they go back to the table view, as that's the only time the update is needed) it's causing a decent performance loss.

I don't get why it's calling it though. I'm not saving the data with `NSManagedObjectContext` into the Core Data store, so why does it care? I only call that when `viewWillDisappear` is called, indicating that they're leaving the view, likely to go back to the table view which is where I want it!

Basically, how do I get it to only call `configureCell:` when it needs to/when I ask it to write the data to Core Data? It's calling it hundreds of times as is.

Comment: What is the purpose of "moving the position of the user" (whatever that means) as the user reads?

Comment: To track where they are. Part of the function of my app is tracking at their specified reading rate where their position should be, so it basically increments their position at a specified rate. Simply for visual cue (until they leave the reading view at which point the position should be saved for the next time they go to read that article).

Comment: Perhaps you could make a copy of the article, and use that in the second view controller -- that should decouple anything you do with it from core data. You could then update the position property of the original article only once in viewWillDisappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you're not persisting the changes to Core Data objects to disk; a change to a Core Data managed object IS a change, and so NSFetchedResultsController acknowledges it.

You could avoid updating the tableview that's not visible by setting NSFetchedResultsController's delegate to `nil` in `viewWillDisappear:`, and setting it back to `self` in `viewDidAppear:`. Also, add a `performFetch:` after setting the delegate.

The "hidden" NSFetchedResultsController will still be receiving all the changes made to the article object in the view that's in the foreground, but will ignore them since it doesn't have a delegate.

When going back to the articles list view, it will have a delegate again, and it will be able to react to all changes.

Comment: Good answer, however I would recommend to set the delegate and perform the fetch (and reload the tableView) in `viewWillAppear:` and unset it in `viewDidDisappear:`. It looks a bit better if the reloading is not visible to the user.